# React-Select SCSS file?

Tags: sass, react-select

I want to change the color of the multi-select item in react-select.

I can see that this has been documented here

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/less/select.less

this line should get the job done for me

```
@select-item-color:                @select-primary-color;
```

except that my project uses SCSS rather LESS.

Can anyone tell me what would be the equivalent SCSS?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  You're using Sass, so why are you looking at the source for LESS?

Comment: My google foo is bad. I was not able to search for the scss file. Sawyer Charles posted the right link.

Comment: You weren't able to traverse to the root of the repo to see if maybe there was a Sass version either?

Comment: yup. i just used google. Sorry. I think its a well deserved negative vote. I will be mindful before asking again. my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCSS variables can be found in: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/09dd2553cec30d567eb48148c636c787fed3db15/scss/select.scss

There is no primary color variable set in the scss file, but the scss equivilant of `@select-item-color` is `$select-item-color`.

You can change the color like this

`$select-item-color: #007eff;`

Comment: The link no longer works